# Math.js access a single element in a matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, math.js

It looks like a too basic job. However, I can't do it.

I added `math.js` to my HTML code

```
<script src="js/math.min.js"></script>
```

I define a matrix in firefox console:

```
var M = math.matrix([[1,0,0,4],[0,1,0,2],[0,5,1,9],[11,2,3,1]]);
```

So far everything is good.

```
M
Object { _data: Array[4], _size: Array[2], _datatype: undefined }
```

Now, I want to access a single element of the matrix:

```
M.index(1,2)
```

And I get an error

> TypeError: M.index is not a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It looks like you need to use `math.index`](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html#getting-or-replacing-subsets).

```
M.subset(math.index(1, 2));
```

But the preferred method, as pointed out by it's author, is using `.get`.

```
M.get([1, 2]);
```

As of the time of this writing, this feature is preferred but documentation is still catching up.

Comment: Thanks, it does work. But should it be such a long process compared with normal array? In other languages it is just like `M[1][2]` or `M.at(1,2)`

Comment: @ar2015 That's just how the library designers built it. You can't overload the `[]` operator in Javascript so they couldn't allow you to do `M[1][2]`. As for why they didn't give that method to the matrix "class", you'd have to ask them.

Comment: Is there any way that I add a patch function to the existing class?

Comment: @ar2015 If you can get access to the main matrix constructor, then you can extend it's prototype and add whatever you want. [I also found this hiding in their codebase](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/1f000925b778c06ef8a0fd788deee840bcf78ea5/lib/type/matrix/Matrix.js#L126) that matrices may implement a `get` function. `M.get([1, 2])` but since I couldn't find strong docs on it, be wary.

Comment: I'm the author of math.js using math.index is indeed verbose, it's necessary because we can't overload JS operators. You can indeed safely use Matrix.get and Matrix.set to get/set individual values of a Matrix. We're currently working on documenting this, these matrix methods where missing in the docs.

Comment: @JosdeJong Was this ever included in the docs? Looking at the matrices doc page, it still only mentions subset/index method for this. I can't actually find an example usage of set but maybe its on a different page in the docs?

Comment: Good point, I don't see anything related in the docs either. Not sure why it wasn't addressed. Any help improving the docs would be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from `M.get([1, 2])`, you can also do -

```
var a = M._data;    // a is a multidimensional array
console.log(a[1][2]);
```